# Crash while deleting cell which is not visible on tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting error on following line:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Also the cell at that indexPath is nil since that table cell is not visible on tableview due to tableview scrolled:

```
TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 5.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (25) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (28), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: How many times you are going to post the same thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245049/app-crash-while-deleting-row-which-is-not-visible-on-tableview

Comment: Oh yes, while editing it got reposted. Deleted duplicate question.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Are you aware of this issue? Solution will be really appreciated.

Comment: Show the whole method where you attempt to delete the row.

Comment: Probably you'r deleting the cell but not deleting the same index value from array.

Comment: remove array value and reload data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to remove item at index 5 in section 0, your code will look like this, In Swift

```
tblList.beginUpdates()
data.remove(at: 5)
tblList.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)], with: .fade)
tblList.endUpdates()
```

Objective-C code will look like this,

```
[_tblList beginUpdates];
[data removeObjectAtIndex:5];
[_tblList deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[_tblList endUpdates];
```